# Problema Simulink: me ha desaparecido el dibujo que indica qué es cada bloque

Tags: matlab

Me están desapareciendo secuencialmente los dibujos dentro de cada bloque que indican qué bloque es (e.g. 1/s para el integrator, -u en unary minus, merge...) y ya solo aparecen bloques en blanco. Siguen realizando su función, pero me gustaría que saliera también el símbolo, ya que de esta manera no es nada visual.

Una vez desaparece el símbolo, cuando trato de importar ese bloque de nuevo desde el library browser también aparece un cuadrado en blanco.

Que yo recuerde no he tocado nada del formato y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cerrar MATLAB y borrar los archivos temporales, estos almacenan registros de configuraciones para el inicio de programas, si los borrar se generaran nuevamente. Si estas en windows presiona Windows + R, se abrirá una ventana y allí escribe **%temp%** dale en aceptar y borra todo lo que te aparezca. Algunos archivos no se podrán borrar, dales en omitir. Luego nuevamente presiona Windows + R y escribe **temp**, así sin las comillas, y de nuevo borra todo lo que se pueda. Luego abre MATLAB/Simulink y mira si el problema sigue.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]